# Sinatra doesn't provide any output

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've recently started messing around with Sinatra and I've come across something that I can't quite wrap my head around.

```
get '/lnb/:date' do
    CSV.foreach("/home/dlind/code/noak/lnb/#{params[:date]}_lnb.csv") do |post|
        "#{post}"
    end
end
```

This yields a blank page when visiting `http://localhost/lnb/2013-11-23` for example. Could anyone care to explain why this is?

Regards,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `CSV.foreach` returns `nil` value.

Try `CSV.read("file")`. This will return an Array of Array with the file values.

Comment: Any hints on how to iterate over this array of arrays in an idiomatic, clean way?

Comment: What do you mean? You can use `each` method to traverse the array, as any other array.

Comment: Well, iterating it like this: `@posts = CSV.read("file") @posts.each do |post| post[0]` renders the error: `undefined method 'bytesize' for #<Array:0x000000022fad80>`. I guess I am doing it wrong.. :P

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to print? The first column?

Comment: Select the first column and concatenate the values: `@posts.map {|post| post[0]}.join(',')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42051/discussion-between-thiago-lewin-and-davidl)

Answer (score 0):

As Thiago says, you're getting a nil value out of the CSV.foreach method.

An alternative...

```
get '/lnb/:date' do
  my_output = String.new
  CSV.foreach("/home/dlind/code/noak/lnb/#{params[:date]}_lnb.csv") do |post|
    my_output << "#{post}\n"
    end
  my_output
end
```